# How to delete the rows corresponding to the selected `yes` input?

Tags: javascript

```js
function removeItem(){
     var _table=document.getElementById("test");
     var len=_table.rows.length;
     for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
        tr=_table.rows[i];
         if(tr.cells[0].firstChild.checked==true){
            tr.parentNode.removeChild(tr);
            }       
        }
    }
```

```html
 <table id = "test" border=1px;>
    <tr><td>to_remove</td><td>f1</td><td>f2</td><td>f3</td></tr>
    <tr><td><input  type="radio" name="delete1">yes<input  type="radio" name="delete1">no</td><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
    <tr><td><input  type="radio" name="delete2">yes<input  type="radio" name="delete2">no</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td></tr>
    <tr><td><input  type="radio" name="delete3">yes<input  type="radio" name="delete3">no</td><td>7</td><td>8</td><td>9</td></tr>
    <tr><td><input  type="radio" name="delete4">yes<input  type="radio" name="delete4">no</td><td>10</td><td>11</td><td>12</td></tr>
    <tr><td><input  type="radio" name="delete5">yes<input  type="radio" name="delete5">no</td><td>20</td><td>11</td><td>12</td></tr>
    <tr><td><input  type="radio" name="delete6">yes<input  type="radio" name="delete6">no</td><td>30</td><td>11</td><td>12</td></tr>
 </table>
 <input type="button" value="remove" onclick="removeItem()">
```

There are some bugs in my js to delete rows.
1.For the first time ,to select two rows to delete.
[image]
2.To click remove, the selected rows was removed, an error occur after removing two rows.
[image]
3.For the second time,to select two rows to delete as the first time do.
[image]
4.To click remove, only one row was removed, same error occur after removing one row.
[image]

There are two bugs for my js code here.
bug1: Which result in the error after removing row?
Why tr is undefined?
bug2: Why only remove one row when to select two rows in my second selection?

Comment: I have updated your code below. Please have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May I suggest this rather clean alternative, using `while` loop?

```js
function removeItem(){
  var table=document.getElementById("test");
  var r=table.rows.length-1;
  while(row=table.rows[r--])
  {
    if(row.cells[0].firstChild.checked==true) row.remove();
  }
}
```

```html
<table id = "test" border=1px;>
    <tr><td>to_remove</td><td>f1</td><td>f2</td><td>f3</td></tr>
    <tr><td><input  type="radio" name="delete1">yes<input  type="radio" name="delete1">no</td><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
    <tr><td><input  type="radio" name="delete2">yes<input  type="radio" name="delete2">no</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td></tr>
    <tr><td><input  type="radio" name="delete3">yes<input  type="radio" name="delete3">no</td><td>7</td><td>8</td><td>9</td></tr>
    <tr><td><input  type="radio" name="delete4">yes<input  type="radio" name="delete4">no</td><td>10</td><td>11</td><td>12</td></tr>
    <tr><td><input  type="radio" name="delete5">yes<input  type="radio" name="delete5">no</td><td>20</td><td>11</td><td>12</td></tr>
    <tr><td><input  type="radio" name="delete6">yes<input  type="radio" name="delete6">no</td><td>30</td><td>11</td><td>12</td></tr>
 </table>
 <input type="button" value="remove" onclick="removeItem()">
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
function removeItem(){
     var _table=document.getElementById("test");
     var len=_table.rows.length
     for(var i=len-1;i>=0;i--){
        tr=_table.rows[i];
         if(tr.cells[0].firstChild.checked==true){
            tr.parentNode.removeChild(tr);
            }       
        }
    }
```

```html
 <table id = "test" border=1px;>
    <tr><td>to_remove</td><td>f1</td><td>f2</td><td>f3</td></tr>
    <tr><td><input  type="radio" name="delete1">yes<input  type="radio" name="delete1">no</td><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
    <tr><td><input  type="radio" name="delete2">yes<input  type="radio" name="delete2">no</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td></tr>
    <tr><td><input  type="radio" name="delete3">yes<input  type="radio" name="delete3">no</td><td>7</td><td>8</td><td>9</td></tr>
    <tr><td><input  type="radio" name="delete4">yes<input  type="radio" name="delete4">no</td><td>10</td><td>11</td><td>12</td></tr>
    <tr><td><input  type="radio" name="delete5">yes<input  type="radio" name="delete5">no</td><td>20</td><td>11</td><td>12</td></tr>
    <tr><td><input  type="radio" name="delete6">yes<input  type="radio" name="delete6">no</td><td>30</td><td>11</td><td>12</td></tr>
 </table>
 <input type="button" value="remove" onclick="removeItem()">
```

just go in opposite direction to stay in the loop range (the length is decremented each time you are deleting the row)

Answer (score 1):

I have updated your snippet. As you are removing the row while looping you should loop from the last element.

```js
function removeItem(){
     var _table=document.getElementById("test");
     var len=_table.rows.length
     for(var i=len-1;i > 0;i--){
        tr=_table.rows[i];
         if(tr.cells[0].firstChild.checked==true){
            tr.parentNode.removeChild(tr);
            }       
        }
    }
```

```html
<table id = "test" border=1px;>
    <tr><td>to_remove</td><td>f1</td><td>f2</td><td>f3</td></tr>
    <tr><td><input  type="radio" name="delete1">yes<input  type="radio" name="delete1">no</td><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
    <tr><td><input  type="radio" name="delete2">yes<input  type="radio" name="delete2">no</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td></tr>
    <tr><td><input  type="radio" name="delete3">yes<input  type="radio" name="delete3">no</td><td>7</td><td>8</td><td>9</td></tr>
    <tr><td><input  type="radio" name="delete4">yes<input  type="radio" name="delete4">no</td><td>10</td><td>11</td><td>12</td></tr>
    <tr><td><input  type="radio" name="delete5">yes<input  type="radio" name="delete5">no</td><td>20</td><td>11</td><td>12</td></tr>
    <tr><td><input  type="radio" name="delete6">yes<input  type="radio" name="delete6">no</td><td>30</td><td>11</td><td>12</td></tr>
 </table>
 <input type="button" value="remove" onclick="removeItem()">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code :-

```
$("#test").find("td:contains('Yes')").closest('tr').remove();
```

**Edit 1**

```
function removeItem()
 {
     $("#test").find("td:contains('Yes')").closest('tr').remove();
 }
```

**Edit 2**

Or you can Try

```
function checkMatch()
{
    $("#test tr.thisRow").each(function() {
        var thisRow = $(this);
        var match = thisRow.find(".match");

        // note the `==` operator
        if(match.text() == "yes") {
            thisRow.hide(); 
            // OR thisRow.remove();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: don't forget to reference `jQuery` for using this code

Answer (score 0):

Just another solution http://jsfiddle.net/pmankar/Bnuy7/1064/

Decrease `i` and `len` value to point correctly and stay in loop.

```
i=i-1;
len = len - 1;
```